# Why am I getting a frame number of 2?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, page-numbering, matrices

Using tikz/matrix inside beamer, I have several slides with a wrong page/frame count.

Why is that so, and how can I avoid it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Bar}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes]
    {42&42\\23&23\\};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This gives me a frame number of 2/2 even though there is only one slide.
I use tikz/matrices to write (category theory-ish) diagrams with arrows because diagrams.sty didn't work in beamer, and then, I use [fragile] for the code to compile because of the `&`.

EDIT:
I found a way to solve the problem, but I'm still interested in explications (and reproduction of the problem, as it seems not every one has this bug.
I'm using TeTex and beamer-3.07, both from the FreeBSD ports, so maybe it's a compatibility bug or an old version issue…)

Comment: I get a regular 1/1

Comment: @egreg: I get 2/1 on first pass (with pdflatex), and 2/2 on second pass…

Comment: I always get 1/1.

Comment: I get 1/1 also with beamer 3.07 on a TeX Live 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum, the following solved the issue, for some reason.

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Bar}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes]
    {42\&42\\23\&24\\};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: So this sounds as though it's a bug with what happens when beamer writes a "fragile" frame to a file and then reads it back in again.  However, as you're using a very old version of beamer, the best solution is as Stefan says: upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

In 2006, support for [teTeX](http://www.tug.org/tetex/) has been stopped. I recommend installing [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) 2011, which is also available for FreeBSD. It also contains a newer version of `beamer`. With TeX Live, I get the correct behavior for your example, a single frame numbered 1/1.

Comment: For FreebBSD, you use the "unofficial" port? Because it's not in my port tree, afaik.